# Am I installing Mongodb's package into my project correctly?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm working on a project that's shared on Git for others to use as well and I need mongodb dependencies in the project in order to access my database on the cloud.

However, my code is never getting past the connection line: (this is written in a .js file)

```
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
```

I'm testing by printing to a canvas and alerts, but anything after this line won't print or alert.

I'm assuming there's something wrong with the way I installed the mongodb package into the project, but I'm not sure? Is there a specific way I should go about doing this?

When I install mongodb, I use `npm install mongodb` and the result is:

```
npm WARN groundstation-website@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN groundstation-website@1.0.0 No license field.

+ mongodb@3.3.5
added 1 package and audited 9 packages in 1.077s
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

edit: here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
'use strict';

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
ctx.font = "20px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "white";

ctx.fillText("text", 10, 100);    // will print

//code here won't print to ctx
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
//won't print
ctx.fillText("text", 10, 100);
});
```

Comment: The [mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) package is for running in `nodejs`. They have the `stitch` libraries for browser based connections.

Comment: Also of note, `var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;` is not a "connection" line. That would only get the client object that could then be configured and told to connect.

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't initialised your project yet:

```
npm init
```

afterwards:

```
npm install mongodb --save
```

in your code:

```
let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
```

Comment: I already have a package.json and package-lock.json file. I guess that means that my project has already been initialized?

Comment: check in your package.json file if mongodb is installed

Comment: It is: `"devDependencies": {
    "mongodb": "^3.3.5"
  }`

Comment: instead, it should be inside the `dependencies` object. while install you should run install command with `-S` and in the project directory.

Comment: there is an error somewhere else then. if your mongo package wouldn't be set up correctly, you'd receive an error message

Comment: Yeah, nothing works so far. I'm trying to compile my .js file locally, but since I'm using `$(document).ready(function() {` my compiler is telling me that `$ is not defined` and I can't get past that, even though when I run my website server, the jQuery is working perfectly up until the mongo connection

Comment: Could it be that mongodb and jquery don't work well together? The connection is fine when I run it locally without `$` but when I try running it on the server with the `$(document).ready...` none of the alerts go through after the mongo connection call

Comment: You really should move that database part to a server sided code, for security reasons. And without actually viewing at your code i can't say anything.

Comment: I just edited my post. I want to print to the html as I go through the database and I wouldn't know how to do it otherwise